# How to loop through json with multiple objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have some json-code which has multiple objects in it, as such:

```
[
    {
        "MNGR_NAME": "Mark",
        "MGR_ID": "M44",
        "EMP_ID": "1849"
    },
    {
        "PROJ_ID": "88421",
        "PROJ_NAME": "ABC",
        "PROJ_ALLOC_NO": "49"
    }
]
```

And my JSON loop snippet is

```
function ServiceSucceeded(result) 
{       
  for(var x=0; x<result.length; x++) 
  {      
    alert(result[i].MNGR_NAME);  
    alert(result[i].MGR_ID);     
    alert(result[i].EMP_ID);  
    alert(result[i].PROJ_ID);  
    alert(result[i].PROJ_NAME);  
    alert(result[i].PROJ_ALLOC_NO);  
  }    
}
```

When I implement it displays alerts that say `undefined` since `result[0]` keys != `result[1]` keys.

Eg: `result[0].MNGR_NAME` (1st Array) gives you `"Mark"` but `result[1].MNGR_NAME` (2nd Array) is not at all in the array and hence gives you `undefined`

Could you please let me know how to address? I should not get `undefined`.

Comment: *"I should not get `undefined`"* - So, what would you like to get instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use

```
for(index in result) {
    var obj = result[index];
    for(objectIndex in obj) {
        if(objectIndex != "PROJ_ALLOC_NO") {
            // Only alert if the key of the object is not PROJ_ALLOC_NO
            alert(objectIndex + ": " + obj[objectIndex]);
        }
    }
}
```

This loops over the array, then over the object and displays every key and value of the objects!

Comment: @ Tomalak: Undefined should be skipped and only values should be displayed

Comment: With my solution, there will be no "undefined", you will only see the real values that are in your object or array. Test it out and see if it works.

Comment: You should add some .hasOwnProperty() checks in case someone has extended Array's prototype, if you're going to use the for...in construct.

Comment: @Willem: Thanks for your inputs. How will i be able to skip a particular value from JSON? Assume from my JSON i want to skip PROJ_ALLOC_NO (i dont want to display/alert PROJ_ALLOC_NO) . Please advise.

Comment: I think you can figure that out yourselves, it's very easy. Still, updated my code with your example.

Comment: @WillemMulder: Thanks for your help. I had fixed it already.And.. is there a way to replace/format objectIndex value to proper names? Say MNGR_NAME to Manager Name, PROJ_NAME to Project name ?

Comment: As that is unrelated to this question, you better ask that in another question..! Is my answer here acceptable?